# Jquery doesnt work on payment gateways woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide a div when an option is selected:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery('#Plaats').val() == "option_a") {

        jQuery(".payment_method_cod").hide();
    }
});
```

On this example, $payment_method_cod doesn't hide but if i change it to another div ID ( for example, #payment ) it works!

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance that other code might run which will result in not hiding the div you wanted. So what i would suggest is run this code the bottom of the site.

You can hook this code to the footer of the site using `wp_footer` hook

Comment or ask me if you have any doubts.

**After Inspecting Questioner site.**

Actually it is `class` not `id`. Please check it well. So the code should be follows

```
jQuery('.payment_method_cod').hide();
```

Whole code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery('#Plaats').val() == "option_a") {

        jQuery('.payment_method_cod').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought this was maybe the case. But i load the script in the footer, just above </body> with this code:

`code`<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/add-ons.js"></script>`code`

Do i maybe load the script wrong? It works with other divs.

Comment: Can i inspect your site?

Comment: Yes, the URL is www.avondwinkelhoofddorp.nl
Add a product to the cart from more then 15 euro. 
Then go to avondwinkelhoofddorp.nl/afrekenen

When you inspect the website. Before the closing body tag i load a script which calls add-on.js.
At the moment, the script needs to hide the word ( CONTANT ).
This word is the first payment method that needs to hide, but it doesnt. If i target a element like "lftd" , it works!

Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: hi, i think your shop is closed. So i couldn't check your checkout page

Comment: Ow sorry, i opened it for you now. The checkout page is now available.

Comment: Thanks for your update. The code still doesn't work. Do you think its maybe because the payment methods are also loaded in jQuery? Because first the .payment_method_cod class is hide, and after some milliseconds the class shows up again(still strange because i load the file just before the </body> ).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I got it !! Thanks Rajesh!

Answer (score 0):

I think the script loaded to quick because the payment part of woocommerce is also done with jQuery. After adding in the setTimeout() function it worked!